# Music headphone recommendation

Tags: headphones, music

I'm looking for some new over-ear / circumaural headphones in the region of £40-50 (about $45-60 USD before tax). They'll be connected directly to my PC, primarily for listening to music (all sorts) and a little gaming (but not looking for a headset).

Not looking for wireless or noise-cancelling, just a nice pair of headphones that sound good and above all, are comfortable for long periods of wear (say a couple of hours). All suggestions are welcome, or any thoughts on the Pioneer MS5T I'm looking at.

Comment: Do you have a specific audio profile that you want? (iex. Big bass vs. good high range production). In general, Skullcandy headphones are typically priced around your wish list price and will give you decent audio vs. price. Bose headphones Quiet Comforts are very comfortable with excellent sound but are probably above your price point.

Comment: Yeah a quick Google gives £289 for the Bose QuietComfort 35 II so I'll probably give those a miss :-) I'd say a rounded profile - I'm not interested in excessive bass. Whatever profile the Klipsch Image S4 are, I liked those very much.